# Finding the maxing value of an attribute in mongoDB using casbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I am a newbie to casbah and mongodb. I am trying to write a scala code to find max value of of a column.

For example:

```
  {"_id"=1,value = "a"}
  {"_id"=2,value = "b"}
  {"_id"=3,value = "c"}
  {"_id"=4,value = "d"}
```

The program should display the max number of id as 4
Could you please let me know how to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite basic stuff, so I really recommend looking through the [MongoDB tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/crud-introduction/) to get a basic grounding.  Alternatively, there is a free [online education platform](https://university.mongodb.com/) from MongoDB!

Onto the matter at hand - how do you find the maximum `_id`?  The way to find the maximum is to simply sort the data in descending order and take the first item. As `_id` is automatically indexed this will be a cheap operation.  There is a [findOne method](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/api/index.html#com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection@findOne[A,B,C](o:A,fields:B,orderBy:C,readPrefs:com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.ReadPreference,maxTime:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration)(implicitevidence$18:A=%3Ecom.mongodb.casbah.commons.TypeImports.DBObject,implicitevidence$19:B=%3Ecom.mongodb.casbah.commons.TypeImports.DBObject,implicitevidence$20:C=%3Ecom.mongodb.casbah.commons.TypeImports.DBObject):Option[MongoCollectionBase.this.T]) that takes a query, the fields to return and a sort document and using that we can get the document with the highest `_id`:

```
  // Add some test data:
  collection += MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1, "value" -> "a")
  collection += MongoDBObject("_id" -> 2, "value" -> "b")
  collection += MongoDBObject("_id" -> 3, "value" -> "c")
  collection += MongoDBObject("_id" -> 4, "value" -> "d")

  // findOne
  val query = MongoDBObject() // All documents
  val fields = MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1) // Only return `_id`
  val orderBy = MongoDBObject("_id" -> -1) // Order by _id descending

  // Run the query
  collection.findOne(query, fields, orderBy)
```

In the findOne we only return the `_id` field meaning we can take advantage of the index only to look up this data as we don't need any other data from the document.

FindOne returns an `Option[MongoDocument]` and the containing document will contain the highest `_id`.

Comment: First of thanks for the response. I tried the similar code that you mentioned. But i get an error-"Resource Path Location Type type mismatch;  found   : com.mongodb.casbah.commons.Imports.DBObject     (which expands to)com.mongodb.DBObject  required: com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.ReadPreference(which expands to)  com.mongodb.ReadPreference". I think findOne doesnt accept more than 2 values. Could you please  help me ?